# Extreme collinearity for Random Forest?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, cart, caret

My data have 450 observations and 2200 predictors that I want to use to train a RF model to classify 4 classes. However, about 2165 of the predictors are very highly correlated to each other. The way I found it was running the following code:

```
cor_matrix = cor(training[, -1]) # ignore y
highly_correlated = caret::findCorrelation(x = cor_matrix, cutoff = .9, names = T)
length(highly_correlated)
```

As most of my variables are highly correlated, what would you suggest me to do? Should I go ahaed and train my model without worrying too much about it or should I choose another algorithm?

I ran RF model both with and without doing preprocessing (PCA) and all I could achieve was about 36% accuracy. What are my options?

````
#my model without PCA
model_rf = caret::train(class ~ ., data = training,
                 method = "rf",
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3))

#my model with PCA
trc = caret::trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, preProcOptions = list(thresh = .95))
model_rf_pca = caret::train(class~., data = training,
                     method = "rf", preProcess = c("pca"),
                     trControl = trc)
```
````

Comment: Just an idea. Did you try to regularise your RF model ? Maybe max depth or minimum number of samples in each leaf ?

Comment: [tag:regularization]

Comment: @Thomas is regularization possible using caret or randomForest packages in R (I have never done that before so any hint will be appreciated greatly)?

Comment: "Hyper-parameter tuning" is another name for regularization. One of caret's main design goals is to facilitate hyper-parameter tuning. The documentation will tell you more.